# Filter jobs by tag, similar to the Stack Overflow main page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Is anything like that planned for development (in the works already, declined at some early stage, etc.)?

It is weird that by now such simple and intuitive feature have not been implemented. For example, I would like to show [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tags in highlight (aka favorite) and hide [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). It turns out for me that 95% of tags belong to another stack; those jobs now take considerable time to weed out manually.

It can work in the same way the Stack Overflow main page currently works, for starters. If anyone has a better idea of how job tag filtering should work, please feel free to share your thoughts.

Comment: I guess not many people using careers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already have most of these capabilities but they're a little bit hidden at the moment. There's an active project to begin addressing the confusing aspects of jobs so this will improve in the coming weeks.

If you click on the cog [image: Match Preferences] in the [matches](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) tab we allow you to configure the tags that you want to work with and those that you dislike. This is the same as the fields used by the CV editor. We also allow you to configure things like salary, seniority and industry preferences.

[image: Match Preferences Editor]

All these preferences feed into the algorithm used to present a list of jobs we think you'll be interested in. Since last week we also allow you to subscribe to the results of that algorithm.

[image: Match Alerts]

In addition we support filtering the entire pool of jobs using [advanced search syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search-jobs). E.g. `[c#] -[php]` finds all jobs that have the `c#` and without the `php` tag.

Comment: Ah, I see. This definitely helps. It would be nice to modify these filters inline with the job summary. For example, introduce an X option to hide a job, it will prompt why, you can choose one of the tags to block, or block company name, or just hide this specific job. Often I browse through jobs and even though it's generally relevant, it does not make sense to review same position multiple times. The idea is this - no new jobs - don't show me anything.

Comment: Another useful feature to this would be companies specifying acceptable candidate location. For example, if a US company is accepting remote candidates, they should be able to specify which country, either US, US/Canada, World etc. and it only should fall under my radar if I satisfy those requirements. I'm in Canada and most of US remote jobs require residency in US. Currently to discover this I need to click though and read description.

Comment: @Neolisk thanks for the feedback, I'll get it added to the list of things we consider as part of the revamp. It's worth noting that we already do what you mention in your second comment; employers specify the regions or countries they want to advertise their jobs in and candidates can specify the areas they are allowed to work in (locations in match preferences). If you're seeing jobs that require visa for the US and are advertising in Canada then you can let us know by flagging the listing and we'll get in contact with the employer.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't think location based remote ever worked for me. For example - http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/36249/net-developer-avl-digital-group?searchTerm=C%23&offset=11&allowsremote=true is only limited to certain states in US. In my "cog" I indicated Mississauga ON and Canada (expecting to see remote in Vancouver for example, if they accept from anywhere in Canada).